# Map UnsupportedMediaTypeException using ExceptionMapper

Tags: spring, rest, jax-rs

Is there a place where it is clearly documented that I cannot map UnsupportedMediaTypeException (because it's a rest easy exception and not custom application exception) using the javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper?

I want to prove that to my client. Or another thing I would like to do is map this exception to a Response that can be fetched at the client to show the error. Right now when this exception is thrown it provides no information to the client as the application ends abruptly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can map this exception. Why not? Do you get an error?

This code should do the job

```
@Provider
public class EJBExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnsupportedMediaTypeException>{

  Response toResponse(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnsupportedMediaTypeException exception) {
    return Response.status(415).build();
  }

}
```

Don't forget to declare that provider in Spring configuration file.

If you want to provide more information to the client create class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Error{
   private String message;
   //getter and setter for message field
}
```

and then you can

```
@Provider
public class EJBExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnsupportedMediaTypeException>{

  Response toResponse(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnsupportedMediaTypeException exception) {
    Error error = new Error();
    error.setMessage("Whatever message you want to send to user");
    return Response.entity(error).status(415).build();
  }

}
```

If you don't want to use Error entity simply pass a string to `Response.entity()` call.

If you want to catch whatever is thrown in you application create generic exception mapper:

```
@Provider
public class ThrowableMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    public Response toResponse(Throwable t) {

        ErrorDTO errorDTO = new ErrorDTO(code);
        return Response.status(500).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that if the exception thrown by the business logic i.e. if I as a developer choose to throw the exception, the mapper works. But if the same exception is thrown internally say if @Consumes annotation fails to validate the content-type the mapper is not invoked.

Comment: Try to create exception mapper for Throwable class (see updated answer)